# Rails 4 - How to Access Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am uploading images which POSTs the following params:

```
Parameters: {"url"=>"https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image014.jpg",
"filepath"=>"/uploads%2F1381509934146-1t5a44loikwhr529-1d68490743e05a1287fea45ed4ed9e59%2Fslide0005_image014.jpg",
"filename"=>"slide0005_image014.jpg", 
"filesize"=>"30807", 
 "filetype"=>"image/jpeg", 
 "unique_id"=>"1t5a44loikwhr529", 
 "choice"=>["https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image014.jpg"]}
```

And here is my form:

```
<%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: choices_url, callback_param: "choice[]", id: "s3-uploader" do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start"> 
<% end %>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
#app/controllers/choices_controller

def create
@choice = Choice.create!(choice_params)
  if @choice.persisted?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to choices_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end

def choice_params
  params.require(:choice).permit(:url, :filepath, :filename, :filesize, :filetype)
end
```

But, it returns the **error**:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007f903e380060>):
  app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:49:in `choice_params'
  app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?  All I would like to do is:

1) Add the "url" param to the DB
2) Titlelize the "filename" param and then submit that to the DB.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### why ?

`require` works like `params[:some_key]`, except it raises `ActionController::ParameterMissing` when the value returned is blank.

This is handy because it allows, using `rescue_from`, to render a `400: bad request` error in this case.

#### what to do ?

So you have to wrap your params so that when you call `require(:choice)` you get a hash.

Unfortunately `s3_upload_form` does not seem to support the same builder syntax as `form_for`, that would allow you to do :

```
<%= form_for :s3_upload do |f| %>
    <% f.file_field :file %>
<% end %>
```

resulting in a params hash like this :

```
 { s3_upload: {file: <SomeFile ...>} }
```

So my advice would simply be to drop the `require` call, and to put `:choice` along the other arguments passed to `permit`.

If you want to still have the benefits of the `require` method (that is, checking if a param is missing), you can always do something along the lines of :

```
def choice_params
  params.permit(:foo, :bar, :baz).tap do |p| 
    p.each_key{ |k| p.require k }
  end
end
```

this would raise an exception if any of the permitted parameters is missing.

Comment: So, how would I wrap my params to get the hash?  I am not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Excellent!  This helped very much, and fixed my issue.  One last question, however.  How would I go about "titleizing" the filename prior to the `create` action?

Comment: to 'titleize', simply use... [titleize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/titleize). You will also have to extract the file name from your string : `File.basename( params[:filename], File.extname(params[:filename]) )`. See [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) for more info. Also, you shouldn't do that in the controller, do it in your `Choice` class instead